# Migrating VMs from Hyper-V 2008 R2 to 2012

Tags: windows-server-2008, hyper-v, migration, windows-server-2012

I have a machine in house which i am planning on Migrating from Windows Server 2008 R2 with HyperV to 2012 with HyperV. I am trying to figure out the easiest way of doing the migration... Most of the VMs are living on a small iSCSI NAS/SAN, with both VHDs and metadata stored there. Based on [This MSDN Blogs post](http://blogs.technet.com/b/keithmayer/archive/2012/09/13/migrating-to-microsoft-hyper-v-server-2012-from-2008-r2-and-vmware-winserv-hyperv-itpro-vmware.aspx#.UI54CHUXy5w) I need to manually export each VM and then re-import them on the 2012 box. Is that the only option? Is there a quicker way? Also, if space is limited, when an export completes, does it delete the original VM? or should i manually do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fastest way is likely to ugprade the 2008 box to 2012. Then they are in 2012. And you can move them around.

Export does not delete the original VM.

Comment: yes then at this point he could do a shared nothing live migration!

Comment: So, Windows 2008 R2 -> 2012 upgrade works? Might try that out! thanks!

Comment: Sure it works. Why you think it is not possible? I would advice reinstalling the box, but after the upgrade you can use live migration to move teh VM's to another hyper-v server ;) Makes things Easier. Remember to take a backup first.

Comment: Thanks TomTom... Never though of upgrading a server... always though of starting from scratch! thanks for the tip though! :)

Comment: Ok, so by the looks of things, my main workstation will be the easiest to upgrade, so this will work for it... My Mac Pro, on the other hand, will need a full reinstall... only a handful of VMs on there, so a quick Powershell script should do the job.

Answer (score 0):

There is a script from [Ben Armstrong, the VirtualPC guy](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/virtual_pc_guy/archive/2012/02/08/powershell-script-for-exporting-a-virtual-machine.aspx) which shows you how to export a VM using Powershell. Not tried it yet, so dont know about the space issues yet...